# The Thread generates output as None and produces the same result in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Here is my code and the output that I received:
**Code**

```
from iqoptionapi.stable_api import IQ_Option
import time
import threading
import pandas as pd
goal="EURUSD"
email = "email"
password = "password"
Candles_Required = 3 
ANS=[]
print("login...")
I_want_money=IQ_Option(email,password)
I_want_money.suspend = 0.1
Threads = []
times = [1565257105, 1565197105, 1565137105]
print("All Times Series : ",times)
def candles_history(tt):
    global goal,ANS,times
    print(times[tt])
    data=I_want_money.get_candles(goal, 60, 1000, times[tt])
    ANS =data+ANS
    print("Executed Time : ",tt)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv("AllTimes//"+str(times[tt])+".txt",   index=False)
    return len(data)

for i in range(Candles_Required):
   t = threading.Thread(target = candles_history,args=(i,) ) 
   Threads.append(t) 
   t.start()
   print(i," Process Started")  
for thread in Threads:    
    while thread.is_alive():
        print("Thread_output : ",thread.join())
        print("Thread is alive")
        pass
print("Len ANS : ", len(ANS))
df=pd.DataFrame(ANS)  
df = df.sort_values('to')  
print(df.head(5))
```

**Output of the above script**

```
login...
All Times Series :  [1565257105, 1565197105, 1565137105]
1565257105
0  Process Started
1565197105
1  Process Started
1565137105
2  Process Started
Executed Time :  1
Executed Time :  0
Executed Time :  2
Thread_output :  None
Thread is alive
Thread_output :  None
Thread is alive
Thread_output :  None
Thread is alive
Len ANS :  3000
                       at    close        from      id       max      min      open          to  volume
0     1565197200001474593  1.12271  1565197140  660039  1.122795  1.12266  1.122755  1565197200     185
1000  1565197200001474593  1.12271  1565197140  660039  1.122795  1.12266  1.122755  1565197200     185
2000  1565197200001474593  1.12271  1565197140  660039  1.122795  1.12266  1.122755  1565197200     185
1     1565197260022881266  1.12296  1565197200  660040  1.122960  1.12271  1.122720  1565197260     321
1001  1565197260022881266  1.12296  1565197200  660040  1.122960  1.12271  1.122720  1565197260     321
```

As the result speaks:
The output after I ran `thread.join` is `None`.
Even the output of the `print(df.head(5))`, the first three values are the same.
I am trying to load 3000 candles from the Iqoption using the API: [IQOPTION_API](https://github.com/Lu-Yi-Hsun/iqoptionapi)
But the output what I get is 3000 candles but all are same. I am not able to guess what is the matter with the threads.

It was taking 3 seconds for the 3000 candles but I wanted get the result in 1 second. Hence tried threads.

Please suggest me what I can do to get the result in one second without fail.
I hope I am clear on this point. If anyone needed more information please let me know in the comments I will explain.

Comment: [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) always returns `None` - you can read it in documentation. It doesn't have method to return value. You my try to assign value directly to external variable or use [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue) to send data. It is safter and recomended in threading's documentation but need more work.

Comment: I tried that also, you see `ANS` is an external variable

Comment: ANS is a list so `append()` data to list, not assign `=` because it removes list with data.

Comment: problem can be also that different threads may want to use the same variable at the same moment and it makes problems. This is why queue is safer.

Comment: Instead of threading you can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and its Pool. In first example (which use Pool) you can see it returns values from all processes. In next examples (which not use Pool) you can see how to use queue to get data. Threads doesn't run at the same time because Python has GIL. Multiprocesses run at the same time because every process use own python interpreter.

Comment: If I append still I get same data

Comment: I tried queue too it returns it act the same. @furas Can you please try it once on your side so that the right problem could be known. I tried many thing. I could not able  to give every attempt of mine here right? I tried multiprocessing too. It did not worked.

Comment: you write data in files `AllTimes//...txt` - what do you get in these files. In your code you use three times the same value in `times = [1565257105, 1565197105, 1565137105]` so you can get three times the same result. What values do you use in full code ?

Comment: I get same result. And by the way they are not same values. Please have a look at them